In MySQL 8.4, can binlog files be deleted?
I recently upgraded to MySQL 8.4, and I just noticed my C drive is almost full. After looking into it, I realized that MySQL has been creating a bunch of files called "binlog.XXXXXX" where XXXXXX is a random number (it appears). The files are stored in C:/PrograData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.4/Data.
Are these just log files that can be deleted, or are they constantly used/referenced by the database.
If they can be deleted, is there a way to have MySQL automatically delete old binlog files. Ideally I can designate how "old".

Binary logs are needed for replication; if you are not using replication, you can delete these at will manually with PURGE BINARY LOGS ....
Or automatically remove binary logs by setting the server variable binlog_expire_logs_auto_purge to ON (the default) and adjusting the server variable binlog_expire_logs_seconds (default 30 days).  The automatic purge of binary logs happens at server start or when you do a FLUSH BINARY LOGS or flush-logs via the mysqladmin command; if your server is on continually, do the flush logs via cron or a windows Scheduled Task.

MySql clearly states this in their documentation. The random number you mention is actually the index
It mentions examples like
PURGE BINARY LOGS {
    TO 'log_name'
  | BEFORE datetime_expr
}

And
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.010';
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2019-04-02 22:46:26';

You need to figure out what is the best fitting for you. You can refer to that document about your query
